# How to test ApplicationController method defined also as a helper method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, helper, rspec2

In my ApplicationController I have a method defined as a helper method:

`helper_method :some_method_here`

- How do I test ApplicationController in RSpec at all?
- How do I include/call this helper method when testing my views/helpers?

*I'm using Rails3 with RSpec2*

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can use an [anonymous controller](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-0/docs/controller-specs/anonymous-controller) to test your ApplicationController, as describe in the RSpec documentation. There's also a section on [testing helpers](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-0/docs/helper-specs/helper-spec).

Comment: Somehow I missed that anonymous controller! Thanks!

Comment: Exactly what I needed to know!

Comment: is it still working in Rails4? I got problem with `No route matches {:controller=>"anonymous", :action => "some action"}`..

Comment: Possibly this issue: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/636. The anonymous controller only has routes for the default resource methods, so rename 'some action' to (say) 'index', or create a route.

Comment: I too wanted to make routes for each method I wanted to test but alas I could not. So I just called every method I wanted to test in the declaration of index and stubbed the non relevant ones out for each separate test using `allow(controller).to receive(:any_non_relevant_method_name).and_return(true)` I did this in a DRY way.

Answer (score 23):

You can invoke your helper methods on `subject` or `@controller` in the specification.

I have been looking for a solution to this problem and anonymous controller was not what I was looking for. Let's say you have a controller living at `app/controllers/application_controller.rb` with a simple method which is not bound to a REST path:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController:Base

  def your_helper_method
    return 'a_helpful_string'
  end

end
```

Then you can write your test in `spec/controllers/application_controller_spec.rb` as follows:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ApplicationController do

  describe "#your_helper_method" do
    it "returns a helpful string" do
      expect(subject.your_helper_method).to eq("a_helpful_string")
    end
  end

end
```

While `@controller` and `subject` can be used interchangeable here, I would go for `subject` as its the RSpec idiomatic way for now.

Comment: Using your answer to test ```current_user``` helper, and it's working gracefully

Comment: This pattern will allow passing specs even for methods that have not been added to `helper_method` arguments. I prefer defining helper methods as `protected` and then speccing with `expect(subject.send(:your_helper_method)).to eq "a_helpful_string"`.

Comment: send is a hack. don't do that

Comment: A hack can serve the purpose, please refer to the alternative if this is the canonical way of doing it. Plus, send is part of the language specification for a reason.